# Manipulating strings in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I've got an anchor tag with a specific URL to which I want to add a class.  I'm currently doing this as follows:

```
$('a[href=http://this.ismyurl.com/folder/file.html]').addClass('red');
```

The problem I have is that this URL is not consistent.  The filename, `file.html` is always the same, so if I could manipulate this string and focus on the last 9 characters (for instance) then I could add a class in the same way. The problem is, I'm not sure how to do this.

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Ronnie

Comment: You might want to limit it to the last 10 ("/file.html"); "file.html" is 'risky' because it will also match "afile.html", "bfile.html", etc. Obviously, the level of danger relates to the actual name of the file :) You might even want to restrict this to "/folder/" too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the attribute end with selector [`$=`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
$('a[href$="file.html"]').addClass('red');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a wildcard in your jQuery selector. I believe this will work:

```
$('a[href$=/file.html]').addClass('red');
```

That will add the 'red' class to all links with an href ending in '/file.html'.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "http://someurl.com"
$('a[href='+url+']').addClass('red');
```

Comment: Thanks for this Mike, however I'm not sure this would work in my case.  I need it to be based on the HTML file, as there are other links that would have the same base URL, to which I don't want to add a class.